# System architecture and design using Visual Studio - real world example

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uml

I am new to Windows and .Net (over 10 years+ experience in C/C++, PHP, Python and a few others, in a *nix environment).

I am looking for an online tutorial (preferably video), that will help me quickly get up to speed with using Visual Studio to model and implement a solution.

ideally, the video will show:

1. How to create UML diagrams with VS (is this even possible out of the box, or do I need extra add-ons?)
2. Generate code from the UML diagrams (is this possible?)
3. Design and create unit tests for the code

I would be very grateful for any links that would show me how to carry out the above using Visual Studio.

For the record, I am already familiar with UML, and do not necessarily need a tutorial on that. It would be useful if the example/video sets out to solve a "real world" (but simplified) problem, so that it would be more useful than a "hello world" type tutorial.

I will be implementing the code in a .Net language - most likely C#.

Answer (score 3):

There 2 series of videos: [one on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsue/archive/2011/06/15/videos-about-visual-studio-alm-team-foundation-server-2010-on-msdn.aspx) and [one on Channel 9](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsue/archive/2010/07/30/channel-9-video-series-uml-with-vs2010-ultimate.aspx) about creating UML diagrams with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. There are also some [hands-on-labs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briankel/archive/2010/06/25/now-available-visual-studio-2010-rtm-virtual-machine-with-sample-data-and-hands-on-labs.aspx) you can find at the Microsoft ALM Catalyst site.

I'm not aware of any video, but [this topic on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657795.aspx) describes how to generate code from UML diagrams, but you need to install the Visualization & Modeling Feature Pack, which is currently available as part of [Visual Studio 2010 Feature Pack 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/ff655021.aspx), available only with an MSDN subscription.

[This topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409381.aspx) addresses developing tests from your models, but not specifically unit tests. You can follow the links to find more info about unit testing in the topic.

Answer (score 1):

There is a video titled "Solution Modeling with UML in Visual Studio 2010" on the Pluralsight web site [here](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/tableofcontents?courseName=vs2010-uml) Alas, it's not free. I haven't watched it myself so I can't vouch for it, but most of the Pluralsight stuff is high quality.

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition has a project template named "Modeling Project". "Add New Item" or on the "Architecture" menu, "Add New Diagram" opens this dialog:

[image]

Chapter 54 of "Wrox Professional Visual Studio 2010" describes modeling with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate for Architects. It describes and shows the different diagram types, and describes how diagrams can be generated from code - but not how code can be generated from diagrams.

In fact, now that I try a modeling test project, its not obvious what the output of building such a project is.

I generally use Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect for designing and code generation as it can produce diagrams from code and code from diagrams. There is a UML tutorials on their web site. I know that you don't need a UML tutorial per se, but it might be possible to use the Microsoft toolset with their part 2 tutorial to see if VS2010 for modeling suits your needs.

The book from Packt titled "Packtpub Software Testing using Visual Studio 2010" and the book from Manning titled "The Art of Unit Testing with Examples in dot NET" and the book from Addison-Wesley titled "Software Testing with Visual Studio 2010" will probably be all you need to know about testing in Visual Studio.

There is apparently, a Visual Studio for Testers, though I'm no longer current regarding which features are available in which versions of Visual Studio. A comparison page for Visual Studio editions is [here](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/tableofcontents?courseName=mstest)

I just remembered there's another Pluralsight video on testing titled "Unit Testing with MSTest" [here](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/tableofcontents?courseName=mstest)